# Arch Linux: Cannot control fan speed

Tags: linux, arch-linux, fan, speedfan

I just installed arch linux on my laptop and I noticed that my fans are full speed all the time so I tried to fix that.

I followed the wiki guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control) but I am stuck because everytime I run `sensors` I get this output:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:          +45.0C  (crit = +99.0C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +46.0C  (high = +86.0C, crit = +100.0C)
Core 0:         +43.0C  (high = +86.0C, crit = +100.0C)
Core 1:         +43.0C  (high = +86.0C, crit = +100.0C)
Core 2:         +45.0C  (high = +86.0C, crit = +100.0C)
Core 3:         +46.0C  (high = +86.0C, crit = +100.0C)
```

I don't see any output for fans.

I tried adding `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `grub` as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=722729#p722729) but nothing.

Also, I tried running:

```
sudo modprobe w83627ehf force_id=0x8860
```

but then, I `pwmconfig` doesn't work properly.

What should I do?

Comment: Yay! I got the tumbleweed badge...